# ¿Se puede hacer split de un String por una cadena de String con una estructura?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recojo los datos de un xml que tiene como **200** elementos y dentro de esos elementos esta la fecha de cada uno, siendo su estructura asi:

```
2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0
```

Pero por ejemplo hay otros que en vez de tener solo dos fechas tienen 4

```
(2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0 
2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0)
```

Y no se como hacer para recoger solo las fechas en `String` dependiendo de cuantas tenga el elemento concreto.

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que te interesa sacar sólo la fecha a qué refieres?  ¿A que quieres sacar este valor: `2018-05-04` o a que quieres sacar también `2018-02-02`? ¿Una cadena con la primera fecha, o dos cadenas con cada fecha?

Comment: Quizás no lo he formula muy bien, culpa mía, me gustaría sacar de ese string las dos fechas que hay.

Comment: Hola Adr, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Para no dar pie a respuestas que no resolverían de raíz tu problema, explica con toda claridad lo que quieres y qué tipo de dato quieres como resultado. Ya queda claro que quieres obtener las dos fechas que hay en esa cadena, la cual parece que tiene siempre la misma estructura. Ahora debes explicar también si quieres un tipo de dato `String` o un tipo de dato `Date`.  Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/162433/edit) indicando esos detalles que son importantes para una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar extraerla mediante una expresión regular, de la siguiente manera:

```
String date = "2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0";
String newDate = "";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(date);

while (m.find())
{
    // Cada fecha de forma individual:
    System.out.println(m.group(0));

    // Fechas concatenadas en una misma cadena:
    newDate += m.group(0) + " "; 
}

System.out.println(newDate);
```

La salida de la concatenación sería:

```
2018-05-04 2018-02-02
```

Te vale tanto para cadenas con 2, 4 o cualquier número de fechas, ya que va extrayendo la siguiente coincidencia hasta que se quede sin ninguna. Tendrías que utilizar [Pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern) y [Matcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, comprobare si funciona en cuanto pueda.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo pasandole por parametro al **split** un espacio en blanco (" ")

```
String str = "2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0";
String[] resp = str.split(" ");
/**
* resp[0] = 2018-05-04
* resp[1] = 00:00:00.0
* resp[2] = 2018-02-02
* resp[3] = 12:00:00.0
*/
```

Despues puedes **concatenar** dos strings:

```
String part1 = resp[0]
String part2 = resp[1]
String value = part1 + " " + part2; // 2018-05-04 00:00:00.0
```

Si es necesario solo obtener todas las fechas en un String puedes hacerlo con un bucle con indices pares.

```
String val = "2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0 2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0";
String resp[] = val.split(" ");
String print = "";

for (int i = 0; i < resp.length; i = i + 2) {
    print += resp[i] + " ";     
}

System.out.print(print); // 2018-05-04 2018-02-02 2018-05-04 2018-02-02
```

Comment: Si, pero el problema tambien que recojo los datos de un xml que tiene como 200 elementos y cada uno tiene un string diferente de fecha, es decir, por ejemplo el primero con esa estructura pero el segundo varia siendo mas largo..

Comment: @Adr puedes poner algo de código? si todas las fechas que tienes en el XML son iguales a la que has puesto como ejemplo, puedes separarlo por un espacio en blanco y después concatenar Strings de la forma que necesites.

Comment: Chdzma, puedes poner el `i+2` al `for` no ¿?

Answer (score 1):

Dado que nunca sabes cuántas fechas puede haber en la cadena, entonces convendría:

1. hacer grupos de valores por **cada dos espacios en blanco**
2. Con cada uno de esos grupos de valores crear un objeto del tipo `Date` formateado como quieras, e irlo guardando dentro de un array.
3. Al final tendrás un array con todas las fechas que haya en la cadena, el cual podrás usar para lo que necesites.

Sería algo así:

```
String dateString="2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0 2018-02-03 12:00:00.0 2018-02-05 12:00:00.0 2018-02-06 12:00:00.0";

ArrayList<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
String[] stringArray = dateString.split("(?<!\\G\\S+)\\s");

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

for (String dateParts : stringArray) {
    try {
        dateList.add(simpleDateFormat.parse(dateParts));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

for (Date date : dateList) {
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
}
```

En este caso, dado que la cadena que he probado es esta:

> 2018-05-04 00:00:00.0 2018-02-02 12:00:00.0 2018-02-03 12:00:00.0
>   2018-02-05 12:00:00.0 2018-02-06 12:00:00.0

vas a tener un array de fechas con estos valores:

```
2018-05-04
2018-02-02
2018-02-03
2018-02-05
2018-02-06
```

Sin importar las fechas que haya, el código te creará un array con cada una de ellas.

Espero te sirva.